# Using unescaped '#' characters on Ag Grid Enterprise React on Context Menu

Tags: ag-grid-react

When I am using the `Ag-Grid` context menu on application, I get a message on console saying:

> [Deprecation] Using unescaped '#' characters in a data URI body is deprecated and will be removed in M68, around July 2018. Please use '%23' instead. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5656049583390720 for more details.

I really don't get any error, but I'm afraid on the message. Can any one update any thing about this message?

This is the component that use this.sate.columnDefs with renderframework like that:

```js
     <AgGridReact
                        // properties
                        columnDefs={this.state.columnDefs}
                        rowData={consumers.items}
                        animateRows
                        enableColResize
                        enableSorting={true}
                        rowSelection="single"
                        suppressMenuHide={true}
                        enableFilter={true}
                        onCellClicked={this.onCellClicked.bind(this)}
                        onGridReady={this.state.onGridReady}
                        paginationPageSize={10}
                        pagination={true}
                        multiSortKey="ctrl"
                        getContextMenuItems={this.state.getContextMenuItems}
                    />
```

```js
  columnDefs: [
                {
                    headerName: "",
                    suppressFilter: true,
                    width: 30,
                    cellRendererFramework: function (params) {
                        if (params.data.permissions.length > 0) {
                            return <i className="fa fa-ellipsis-v" />;
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    headerName: language.LAST_NAME,
                    field: "person.last_name",
                    enableRowGroup: true,
                    filter: "agSetColumnFilter",
                },
                {
                    headerName: language.FIRST_NAME,
                    field: "person.first_name",
                    enableRowGroup: true,
                    filter: "agSetColumnFilter",
                }
              
               
            ],
            sortingOrder: ["desc", "asc", null],
            getContextMenuItems:          this.getContextMenuItems.bind(this),
            onGridReady: function (params) {

                var sort = [
                    {
                        colId: "person.last_name",
                        sort: "asc"
                    },
                    {
                        colId: "person.first_name",
                        sort: "asc"
                    },
                    {
                        colId: "medical_id",
                        sort: "asc"
                    },
                    {
                        colId: "person.date_of_birth",
                        sort: "asc"
                    }
                ];
                this.gridApi = params.api;
                this.gridApi.setSortModel(sort);
                params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
            }
```

```js
  getContextMenuItems(params) {
        let language = languageActions.getLanguage();
        const { props } = this;
        this.setState({
            showActionDiv: false
        });
        var aResult = [];
        params.node.data.permissions.map((permision, index) => {
            let language = languageActions.getLanguage();
            switch (permision) {
                case "Update":
                    aResult.push(
                        {
                            name: language.VIEW_DETAIL,
                            icon: '<span class="fa fa-edit icon-ag-grid"></span>',
                            action: () => {
                                //console.log(this.props);
                                this.props.toggleShowProfile();
                            }
                        }
                    );
                    break;
                case "Read":
                    aResult.push(
                        {
                            name: language.VIEW_SCHEDULE,
                            icon: '<span class="fa fa-calendar icon-ag-grid"></span>',
                            action: () => {
                                this.props.toggleShowScheduledServices();
                            }
                        }
                    );
                    break;
            }
        });
        aResult.push(
            "separator",
            "copy",
            "csvExport",
            "excelExport",
            "autoSizeAll");
        return aResult;
    }
```

Comment: Can we see some of your code? The context in which `Ag-Grid` is used may be relevant.

Comment: I've already add it, Thanks for the help

Comment: My stack trace: ```(anonymous) @ tabbedLayout.js:42
./node_modules/ag-grid/dist/lib/layout/tabbedLayout.js.TabbedLayout.getMinWidth @ tabbedLayout.js:35
./node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/lib/menu/enterpriseMenu.js.EnterpriseMenu.getMinWidth @ enterpriseMenu.js:142
(anonymous) @ enterpriseMenu.js:60
./node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/lib/menu/enterpriseMenu.js.EnterpriseMenuFactory.showMenu @ enterpriseMenu.js:79
./node_modules/ag-grid-enterprise/dist/lib/menu/enterpriseMenu.js.EnterpriseMenuFactory.showMenuAfterButtonClick @ enterpriseMenu.js:52```